# Mysql multiple table creation

Tags: mysql, create-table

Is there a possibility to execute multiple `CREATE TABLE` within one mysql query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You must do them in multiple queries.

`<incorrect>`However, you can wrap the creation queries in a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html) to allow you to roll back the entire operation if something fails.`</incorrect>`

UPDATE: Ok, as pilcrow points out, each create causes an implicit commit, so you can't use transactions for this. You can, however, wrap the inserts (for a backup restore) in transactions.

Comment: No, you cannot ROLLBACK multiple table creation statements — like many DDL statements they cause an [implicit commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/implicit-commit.html)

Comment: @pilcrow - Wasn't aware of that. I'll update to reflect that fact.